# Why does a prepare message wants a promise that an acceptor is never to accept a proposal numbered less than its propose sequence value? (Paxos)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, distributed-systems

I was studying Paxos from:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf

Recall that Paxos is a distributed system algorithm with the goal that the processes participating in its protocol will reach consensus on one of the valid values.

On page 4 of the paper, at the bottom where they outline what a prepare request looks like it says:

> "A proposer chooses a new proposal number n and sends a request to
>   each member of some set of acceptors, asking it to respond with:
>
> (a) A promise never again to accept a proposal numbered less than n,
>
> (b) ... "

Why does prepare message extract such promise from the set of acceptors that receive such a prepare message? What is the goal and what safety guarantee does it provide? How does it aid Paxos into reaching a consensus to a certain value? How is it crucial so that a majority can reach agreement?

I did some further research to try to answer this question and went to the following yale university notes:

http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/Paxos

These notes try to justify this point by saying:

> "... proposer tests the waters by sending a prepare(n) message to all
>   accepters where n is the proposal number. An accepter responds to this
>   with a promise never to accept any proposal with a number less than n
>   (**so that old proposals don't suddenly get ratified**)... "

Basically, the way they justify that step is by saying so that old proposals don't get ratified/accepted. Which I kind of see why they said that, since if a decision has happened, that rule definitively avoids the consensus from being reversed, which is nice. But, however, the reason I did not feel very convinced about it yet is because it seems to damage termination a lot. What if if a majority was about to be formed in the past and the proposer was ready to send the propose(n) and now because a different prepare(n') was sent its not able to reach agreement? I can't seem to convince myself that that this step is 100% a good idea.

Unless the only reason for that step is because they just want to guarantee that once a value has been chosen/decided, by adopting this rule, its impossible that any old proposal reverses the decision?

Again, I did some further research by reading the yale article and now it says:

> "The rule that an acceptor doesn't accept any proposal earlier than a
>   round it has acknowledged means that the value v in an ack(n, v, n_v)
>   message never goes out of date—there is no possibility that an
>   acceptor might retroactively accept some later value in round n' with
>   nv < n' < n. So the ack message values tell a consistent story about
>   the history of the protocol, even if the rounds execute out of order."

However, its not obvious to me why retroactivity might be bad (unless in the case that I already mentioned). Retroactivity could be good if it somehow manages our protocol to reach consensus. Still the only reason I see for such a rule is so that one doesn't reverse a decision by accident once a value has been agreed on.

---

Author: Leslie Lamport

Title: Paxos made simple

Institution: Microsoft Research

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a concise question to be answered here. The consistency is required for a strong version of the invariant $P2^c$ in the cited paper (which satisfies a chain of implications $P2^c\implies P2^b\implies P2^a\implies P2$). Perhaps retroactive acceptance could somehow form a valid consensus protocol, (since only $P2$ needs to be satisfied), but it would be very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Without N being monotonically incremented this may happen:

1. Proposer P1 get promises from every Acceptor for N=1
2. Proposer P1 goes to slip (e.g. java garbage collection kicks in)
3. Another proposer P2 with N=2 gets promises and gets its value V2 accepted by all acceptors - consensus happened.
4. Proposer P1 wakes up and sends accepts to all, without smaller N being rejected, the consensus will change its decision - broken logic.

You could find other examples, when increasing N is important. Think about case when acceptors already accepted some values and proposers has to respect that.

The important part to understand about epaxos - it does not really have to stop; after a consensus happened, proposers may keep proposing new values and N will keep increasing. The algorithm makes sure that while N keep increasing, the same value is kept being sent to learners.

Since in reality proposers, learners and acceptors are same boxes (each box/server/node runs all three nodes), proposers should stop proposing after their learned about a consensus.